# Restricting sets of alternative and null hypotheses to just two values

Tags: hypothesis-testing, neyman-pearson-lemma

I have encountered this following question quite a few times in different exercises, and have seen some examples using it, however, in the notes and book that I am following, I am unable to find a proof, or, at least, an intuitive explanation to it. The question is basically as follows:

Assume you have some samples $X_1,\dots,X_n$ from a given distribution. If you have a null hypothesis $H_0: \theta\in\Theta_0$ to be tested against $H_1: \theta\in\Theta_1$ where $\Theta_0\cap\Theta_1=\emptyset$. If we would like to do the likelihood ratio test $L_x(H_0,H_1)$ it is **basically** equivalent to doing the likelihood ratio test of $H_0^\prime:\theta=\theta_0$ against $H_1^\prime:\theta=\theta_1$, with $\theta_0\in\Theta_0$ and $\theta\in\Theta_1$.

***Why does this stand true even when the likelihood functions in the likelihood ratio tests are not necessarily increasing over $\Theta_0$? or, if it is not generally true, when is it true? What other restrictive conditions should be imposed?***

To introduce it in a more concrete example, I had to prove that if $X_1,\dots,X_n$ are samples from $Exp(\lambda)$ and $0<\lambda_0<\lambda_1$, finding the most powerful $\alpha$ size test of $H_0:\lambda=\lambda_0$ against $H_1:\lambda=\lambda_1$ also implies that it is a size-$\alpha$ test of $H_0:\lambda\leq\lambda_0$ against $H_1:\lambda=\lambda_1$.